# in php mail function Can we set From attribute as a Word Not Email?

Tags: php, email

In php Mail Function, when we send headers, can we set the "From Mail" to be a Word like "Company Newsletter" Only, not in an email form as newsletter@company.com ?? 
how can we do that ? because writing it is (not in an email form) prevents the email from being sent.

here's my code:

```
  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256\r\n";
```

i have tried what tim suggested , having

```
  $row['SenderMail'] =  "Company Newsletter <Newsletter@ids.com.lb>";
  $headers .= "From:".$row['SenderMail']."\r\n"; 

  $subject=str_replace('%26','&',$row['Subject']);

  @mail($row['DestinationMail'], $subject, $row['Body'],$headers);
```

But still email isn't being sent.any help ?

Comment: Read @Tim's answer again. You still need a valid email address in the header, like `Company Newsletter <noreply@company.com>`

Comment: sorry that is a typing mistake, i have added the email in angle brackets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following :

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: '.$row['SenderMail'].' <'.$row['SenderMail'].'>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Company Newsletter <Newsletter@ids.com.lb>'."\r\n";

mail($row['DestinationMail'], $subject, $row['Body'], $headers);
```

That should do the trick !

Comment: Can you please make a : var_dump($headers); var_dump($row); so we can check the values ?

Comment: i have used $headers .= 'From: '.$row['SenderName'].' <'.$row['SenderMail'].'>'."\r\n"; when i use var_dump, values show only the senderName hence before the angle brackets :   string(130) "MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256 From: IDS - Integrated Digital Systems "

Comment: Do you have this : 
From: '.$row['SenderName'].' <'.$row['SenderMail'].'>'."\r\n";

Comment: You only get : string(130) "MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256 From: IDS - Integrated Digital Systems " ? Where is the "To" header ?

Comment: yes i have this, the To is sent to the mail function after that @mail($row['DestinationMail'], $subject, $row['Body'],$headers); it is the destinationMail

Comment: what does var_dump($row); prints ?

Comment: i replaced the angle brackets by their corresponding html codes, now they appear when we print the values, but still the email is not being sent . thanks for your help :) . now here's what we are printing   string(162) "MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256 From: IDS - Integrated Digital Systems <Newsletter@ids.com.lb > To:z.marji@ids.com.lb "
array(24) { [0]=> string(2) "26" ["MailID"]=> string(2) "26" [1]=> string(21) "Newsletter@ids.com.lb" ["SenderMail"]=> string(21) "Newsletter@ids.com.lb"...etc.

Comment: there's an extra space in "<Newsletter@ids.com.lb >" // a space is missing between "to" and "z.marji@ids.com.lb"

Comment: sadly that was not the problem

Comment: Can you please test with :

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Test <test@test.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Company Test <company@test.com>'."\r\n";
mail('your@email.com', 'test mail', 'test content', $headers);

Comment: and replace "your@email.com" by your own email

Comment: Do you get any php errors? Have you tried to replace `\r\n` with `\n` according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (see note under Additional headers)

Comment: @Laurent Brieu , i tested ur code, didnt work either. the email is not being sent when i add the angle brackets. ..@Alasjo i've tried that.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a valid From: header - note the address is in angle brackets:

`"Company Newsletter <newsletter@company.com>"`

Many email clients will simply show the Company Newsletter in the From column of the interface.

Note that this is not allowed in the Return-Path: header, just the From:

Note 'display name' in RFC 2822 3.4
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i have added my code in the question above,tried  Company Newsletter <newsletter@company.com> but didn't work.

Comment: @user1395625 Insert a space before `<newsletter`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just rechecked and it's working with a basic example like :

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256'."\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'To: Test <your@email.com>'."\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Company Test <company@test.com>'."\r\n"; 

mail('Test <your@email.com>', 'test mail', 'test content', $headers);
```

Under which PHP version are you ? Did you configure your mail server ? Can you please put these lines in top of your script :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Ok now it is solved. i've been testing on Windows operating system, php version 5.2.5  , but now i tested it on linux and the email was sent successfully..why is that ??

Comment: On windows it is still not working, email is not being sent .no php errors or any other errors.

Comment: did you configure your mail server on windows ?

Comment: yes sure, the all email are sent successfully, but when i add these angle brackets, it stops sending.

Comment: please refer yourself to : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes